# blurry video thumbnails in shopify theme

Tags: html, html5-video, shopify, web-frontend

I've an issue with blurry video thumbnails with a shopify theme (Flex from Out of the Sandbox). The image in the middle is a blurry video thumbnail, whereas the top and bottom one are regular sharp product images. [Link to sample product.](https://fashionkraut.myshopify.com/products/aa-top)

[image: Screenshot of Shopify product page with blurry video thumbnail in the center]

I tested the content within different environments:

The video itself is sharp, which is visible when it's being streamed
-> video is not the issue

The video thumbnail is sharp on another theme (Debut from Shopify)
-> Shopify CDN is not the issue, must be the theme I am using

I also uploaded a cover jpeg within Shopify admin which didn't change anything.

I couldn't identify the problem by inspecting with the browser dev tools. Can somebody give me a hint how to fix this?

Comment: Your theme uses 300 x 300 px image as poster that looks blurred when stretched. Edit that to use bigger image.

Comment: Thank you for the hint - changed that code to 800x800 which fixed it. You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

In your liquid code the image URL filter is set to '300x300' (see below image)

[image]

You may just remove this or set it to 1024x1024 for better image.

Hope this info will help you.
Best of luck